# How would i use a wildcard for a specific string in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, wildcard

I have a string which I need to select in a `CASE` statement:

```
LLF_RET_mob
```

However, when I use the following string in my `LIKE` statement in SQL it returns null:

```
%LLF\\_RET_\\_mob%
```

What would be correct syntax to use for this wildcard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `'%LLF\\_RET\\_mob%'` as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  select 1 id, 'aaaLLF_RET_mobbbb' col union all
  select 2, 'aaaLLFRETmobbbb'
)
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE col LIKE '%LLF\\_RET\\_mob%'
```

Or you can use regexp as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'aaaLLF_RET_mobbbb' col UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'aaaLLFRETmobbbb'
)
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(col, r'LLF_RET_mob')
```

Obviously you can use both LIKE or REGEXP_CONTAINS as a condition in CASE statement

Comment: I have two strings below which i need to apply a regex function to in Google BigQuery with its desired outputs:

Input:
1) MERCURE ENGAGEMENT_LaL_FB_TALENT:HENRIQUE_PORTUGAL_WEEK 4_IMAGE CAROUSEL_I19
2) MERCURE ENGAGEMENT_LaL_FB_UGC:_ENGLAND_TBC_WEEK 4_IMAGE CAROUSEL_I25

Output: 
1) HENRIQUE 
2) ENGLAND